# try, try! & try? what’s the difference, and when to use each?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift3, swift2

In [Swift 2.0](http://ahmedabdurrahman.com/2015/08/22/swift-2-0/), Apple introduced a new way to handle errors (do-try-catch).
And few days ago in Beta 6 an even newer keyword was introduced (`try?`).
Also, knew that I can use `try!`.
What's the difference between the 3 keywords, and when to use each?

Answer (score 373, accepted):

**Updated for Swift 5.1**

Assume the following throwing function:

```
enum ThrowableError: Error {

    case badError(howBad: Int)
}

func doSomething(everythingIsFine: Bool = false) throws -> String {

  if everythingIsFine {
      return "Everything is ok"
  } else {
      throw ThrowableError.badError(howBad: 4)
  }
}
```

## try

You have 2 options when you try calling a function that may throw.

You can take responsibility of **handling errors** by surrounding your call within a do-catch block:

```
do {
    let result = try doSomething()
}
catch ThrowableError.badError(let howBad) {
    // Here you know about the error
    // Feel free to handle or to re-throw

    // 1. Handle
    print("Bad Error (How Bad Level: \(howBad)")

    // 2. Re-throw
    throw ThrowableError.badError(howBad: howBad)
}
```

Or just try calling the function, and **pass the error along** to the next caller in the call chain:

```
func doSomeOtherThing() throws -> Void {    
    // Not within a do-catch block.
    // Any errors will be re-thrown to callers.
    let result = try doSomething()
}
```

## try!

What happens when you try to access an implicitly unwrapped optional with a nil inside it? Yes, true, the app will CRASH!
Same goes with try! it basically ignores the error chain, and declares a “do or die” situation. If the called function didn’t throw any errors, everything goes fine. But if it failed and threw an error, **your application will simply crash**.

```
let result = try! doSomething() // if an error was thrown, CRASH!
```

## try?

A new keyword that was introduced in Xcode 7 beta 6. It **returns an optional** that unwraps successful values, and catches error by returning nil.

```
if let result = try? doSomething() {
    // doSomething succeeded, and result is unwrapped.
} else {
    // Ouch, doSomething() threw an error.
}
```

Or we can use guard:

```
guard let result = try? doSomething() else {
    // Ouch, doSomething() threw an error.
}
// doSomething succeeded, and result is unwrapped.
```

One final note here, by using `try?` note that you’re discarding the error that took place, as it’s translated to a nil.
Use try? when you’re focusing more on successes and failure, not on why things failed.

## Using Coalescing Operator ??

You can use the coalescing operator ?? with try? to provide a default value incase of failure:

```
let result = (try? doSomething()) ?? "Default Value"
print(result) // Default Value
```

Comment: Your second code sample (`let result = try doSomething() // Not within a do-catch block`) is to be called from within  a method that is declared as `throws`, right? So, if `doSomething()` fails, so does the outer method too (in turn)?

Comment: Old thread and all but I found that today (Swift 4, Xcode 9.1) try? doesn't auto-unwrap the result. It just leaves it as a normal optional for you to unwrap manually. Not sure if this changed since Swift 2/3 but it is per the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html (see _Converting Errors to Optional Values_). Great explanation of try btw.

Comment: in swift 4, try? does not remove the no calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expressions in my project.

Comment: You could also use `try?` with `??` so it would let you define a default value in one line: `let something:String = (try? whateverIfItThrows()) ?? "Your default value here"`

Comment: Does anyone have trouble remembering try! vs try? vs try, and end up here, time and time again... It might be a sign the language is bloated 

Comment: @BenButterworth Honestly not, so long as you remember that only `try` must be enclosed in a do-catch and the other two not, you can then recognise that `!` and `?` work as standard optional operators.