# I am trying to instantiate a Realm database for Swift 2

Tags: swift2, realm

[I tried some of the solutions given over in stackoverflow but I am getting run time error]
    let realm = try! Realm() 
doesn't throw any error while building but once the app is running, it gives EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.

How can I fix the error in instantiating Realm?

Screenshot of error:
[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to initialize a `Realm` from the default value of a `UIViewControlller`. Be aware, if that's your initial view controller, that this might happen before your AppDelegate's [`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html?hl=ar#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) is executed, from where you might setup the default configuration. But this should happen before you initialize any accessors.

I'd recommend to use *Dependency Injection* to set the Realm from a later point in time, after the application launch is fully finished.

Alternatively you could instead declare your property as implicitly unwrapped optional and initialize it's value in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
var realm: Realm!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.realm = try! Realm()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, you shouldn't define realm as a class property, but rather locally in a `do-try-catch` closure where you perform some realm action (say, `realm.write`).

Moreover, at the line of the error: **if** the statement`let realm = try! Realm` **fails**, you will hit an assert which will cause that the app to crash at runtime (thanks @marius).

Instead, consider using your calls to `Realm()` in some class method, where you handle possible errors/asserts via the `catch` closure.

```
func TryToWriteToRealm(myText: String) {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(myText)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error!")
        // some error handling
    }
}
```

Then call `TryToWriteToRealm(...)` when you want to e.g. Write to your realm.

---

For details of the difference between `try`, `try?` and `try!`, see e.g.

- [try, try! & try? what’s the difference, and when to use each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390611/try-try-try-what-s-the-difference-and-when-to-use-each)

Comment: You don't unwrap implicitly optionals when `try!` fails, but you hit an assert which will cause that the app crashes at runtime.

Comment: @marius you're right, thanks! I just wondered why the runtime error didn't specify `... unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional` (or in similar terms), but this explains it. Thanks, I'll edit the answer.