# swift_unexpectedError when attempting to play audio

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, try-catch

So, I'm using this function to set AVAudioPlayer:

```
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file: String) -> AVAudioPlayer? {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    if let sound = NSDataAsset(name: file) {
        do {
            try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
            try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(data: sound.data, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeWAVE)
        } catch {
            print("error initializing AVAudioPlayer")
        }
    }
    return audioPlayer
}
```

But I'm getting hundreds of reported crashes from users. I'm not able to replicate any crash.

The crashes happen on these two lines:

```
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

sometimes it crashes on the first line, sometimes on the second. How do I fix this? What could be causing these crashes?

Comment: You shouldn't use `try !` if you're wrapping your code in a `do` block.  Just use `try`.

Comment: Yes, that's one half of the problem, but I'd also like to know what caused those crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have no idea of what's the reason of causing the crash(es), but to prevent them, you should replace the `try!` with `try` in the `do` block to let `catch` to be able for handling any expected error. Currently, the `do catch` is only handling the `try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer`, `try! AVAudioSession` and `try! AVAudioSession` *should do cause a crash* if something wrong happened.

To be more clear, consider the following example:

```
enum FirstError: Error {
    case FirstError
}

func throwFirstErrorFunction() throws {
    throw FirstError.FirstError
}

enum SecondError: Error {
    case SecondError
}

func throwSecondErrorFunction() throws {
    throw SecondError.SecondError
}
```

**Case #1:**

```
try! throwFirstErrorFunction() // crash
```

The application should get a crash.

**Case #2:**

```
do {
    try throwFirstErrorFunction()
    //try throwSecondErrorFunction()
} catch (let error) {
    print(error) // FirstError
}
```

It should print `FirstError`.

**Case #3 (what are you facing):**

```
do {
    try! throwFirstErrorFunction() // crash
    try throwSecondErrorFunction()
} catch (let error) {
    print(error)
}
```

The application should get a crash, why? because the `do catch` handles only `try` but not `try!`.

**Case #4 (solution):**

```
do {
    try throwSecondErrorFunction()
    try throwFirstErrorFunction()
} catch (let error) {
    print(error) // SecondError
}
```

It should print `SecondError`. Note that the *first caught error will get handled* -by the `catch` block- and the other `try`s should be skipped.

**Also,**

I'd recommend to check [try, try! & try? what’s the difference, and when to use each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390611/try-try-try-what-s-the-difference-and-when-to-use-each)