# Why can't I use the try? in swift

Tags: swift

Use try? to handling the error in the function
But it shows that "No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression"

```
     if let result:Double = try? finalformular.expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as! Double{
        text = String(result)
        }else{
            text = "Error"
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1TBk.png)

Comment: `expressionValue(with:, context:)` really throws? What's its declaration? Seems to be https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1410363-expressionvalue there is no "throws", so no reason to do a try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [try, try! & try? what’s the difference, and when to use each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390611/try-try-try-what-s-the-difference-and-when-to-use-each)

Answer (score 0):

As error explains, there isn't any method which would throw. If you're using optional binding, you just need to use `as? Double` since you don't know if return type is `Double` and you need to downcast it

```
if let result = finalformular.expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Double {
    text = String(result)
} else {
    text = "Error"
}
```